# Hofstadter sequence using a tail-recursive function in c

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a tail-recursive function of the Hofstadter sequence defined like this:

[image]

So far I've been able to write a recursive funcion which isn't tail-recursive:

```
int f_h(int n)
{
    int h;
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    h = f_h(f_h(f_h(n-1)));

    return(n-h);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look correct -- `h` is never used after being assigned!

Comment: How about simply `return n - f_h(f_h(f_h(n - 1)))`?

Comment: Oh and you should probably change the type from `int` to `unsigned`, to satisfy the requirement that `n` can't be negative.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude still not tail recursive.
the chose between int and unsigned is not really the problem here.

Comment: @duskwuff now is correct

Comment: So you updated the question with the correct version, making this whole question *worthless*? If you figured out the problem, add it as an *answer* instead. Or if you got it from a comment, maybe ask the person posting the comment to post an answer?

Comment: And the function in the image is `n - H(H(H(n - 1)))`, not `H(n - H(H(H(n - 1))))`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude now the function is working, but still isn't tail recursive. I had written that cleary.
(sorry for the mistakes, I was modifing the funcion and I made a mess.)

Comment: @LorenzoAtzeni Are you saying that the last line as to be `return f_h(<something>);` by itself or does it just have include the call to `f_h()` like Someprogrammerdude's comment does?

Comment: @twain249 The last line has to contain only the call to the funcion itself. Otherwise it isn't tail recursive.

Comment: @LorenzoAtzeni. You're going to have to modify your parameter list. For pure tail recursion you need to take in the current value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion

Comment: @twain249 the problem here is that this sequence is due to the fact that i have to call the funcion more than one time. I don't undestand how can I modify the parameters in the proper way.